# Accessing TeamCity Admin Siite

Tags: teamcity

I spent a bit of time installing and setting up the TeamCity 9.0 package and everything was working well.

However after rebooting the machine I cannot access the web administration site. I left the port number being the default port number(i believe 80).

I've checked the Services and both the TeamCity Build Agent and TeamCity Server are running in the Services list.

But I cannot access the site when i use the following url on the server, http://localhost

Can anyone help?

Comment: I changed the ports to 8080 in the server.xml and the buildagent.properties files.

Comment: I ran netstat -nao | findstr ":8080" and found the the is a processid 3240 listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080.

Comment: I ran tasklist | findstr "3240" and ound the the process was java.exe which i assume is the tomcat instance

Answer (score 0):

This was a server 2012 issue with there being a policy that does not allow localhost calls on the server. THERE IS NOTHING WRONG WITH THE Product.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not install TeamCity on Port 80.
All the websites i.e (all HTTP calls are using port 80)

Once this ports gets engaged with other websites, your TeamCity will not work.

Suggestion :

1. Try to change the port while installing the TeamCity Server
2. You can change the port number from buildAgent.properties file which come under conf folder.

Hope this should work fine for you.